# Flash CS4: How can I play a movie clip when a button is clicked

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, button, adobe, movieclip

I want to play a movie clip when I click a button.

**I made 3 states:**

```
inicial (how it looks before anything happens) (up)
hover (plays an animation after waiting 20 frames) (over)
click (plays an animation right away) (down)
```

I placed these movie clips inside of my button's up, over, and down frames. This works great except when I click, i'll need to click and hold for my animation to get past the first frame.

What can I do so that I click on my button and plays the movie clip in its entirety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're creating a button in the IDE:
Because the button "down" state is only registered while its actually "down", you'd need to associate a movieclip outside of the button that is triggered on mouse down.

```
someButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, runClip);

private function runClip(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    _downClip.play();
}
```

You'd need to position it accurately, or wrap it up in another symbol.

...

Or better yet, program the whole thing in AS3 and get away from timeline development...

**update -**

I don't have any preferred tutorials or sites for this, in particular. But just google "as3 button tutorial" and you should get a lot of hits... [this one](http://www.how-to-code.com/as3-actionscript3/as3-buttons/as3-button.html) looks pretty complete.

Oh, wait - I think I posted a class for a basic image button that could be easily altered to function with movieclips from the library... yep, its right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450321/using-custom-graphical-assets-in-pure-as3-project/5451814#5451814). The basic idea should be fairly clear if you have any experience with as3 / object oriented programming. And if its not - google away ;)

Cheers

Comment: nice thanks, any sites you recommend for basic snippets such as hover and clicks with AS3?